# Java: Check if next "field" in array exists

Tags: java, arrays

Ive made this:

```
if( tal[i+1] ){
    if( tal[i] == tal[i+1]){
        match=true;
    }
}
```

But it doesnt seem to work.

I want to check whether the field next to the current (i) exists, in the array tal[].

How can i fix this?

Comment: what is the type of the array?

Comment: Define "doesnt seem to work". What does it do?

Comment: what exactly do you want to check? sounds a little bit weird to me, possible another struture than an array would be appropriate...

Comment: you need to see if the next field in an array exists or per code, are you wanting to check if the two fields are equal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If  by "exists" you mean "is not out of bounds", then you have to check the length:

```
if (i+1 < tal.length) {
  // i+1 is a valid index in tal here
}
```

Comment: Correct me if my logic is wrong, but assuming an array of size 3, and the variable 'i' starting at 0, when 'i' is 2 it will be the last index of the array, and will check if 'i' + 1 < array.lenght (3 < 3), will not go in, I believe the correct one would be to put '<=', because when reach 3 it will already be extrapolating the limit of the array that goes up to size 2 (starting from 0).

Comment: The question is if the "next" element exists (which is true for `i==1` but false for `i == 2`). `2+1 < 3` is false, so this behaves as requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of an array with the `length` field, like:

```
if (tal.length > i + 1) {
    // there is an elemnt at i + 1
}
```

As you did not mention anything about your comparison line (the line containing `==`) I think it is not part of the question.

Although I guess you should put it into a for loop like:

```
for (int i=0; < tal.length - 1; i++) {
    // you can safely do something here involving tal[i] and tal[i + 1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, all his code does is check if the next element of the boolean array is the same as the current element after first checking if the next element is true.
My guess is he thinks it does something else, but without him telling us what that something is it's rather hard to make recommendations for changes.

Comment: How do you know it is a boolean array?